# BQL subquery in the where clause

Tags: acumatica

Hi I am having trouble some BQL syntax what I want to achieve is a BQL statement like the below SQL with nested sub query in the where clause.

```
  SELECT * FROM ARInvoice I 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ARAdjust A WHERE I.RefNbr = A.AdjdRefNbr) > 0
```

Is this possible in BQL if so how would I write this?

Below is what I have got at the moment but this isn't correct I'm getting syntax errors

```
   PXSelect<PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoice,
        Where<PXSelectGroupBy<PX.Objects.AR.ARAdjust, Where<PX.Objects.AR.ARAdjust.adjdRefNbr, Equal<PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoice.refNbr>, Aggregate<Count>>, Greater<Zero>>>>.Select(new PXGraph());
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options to implement this.

**Using Sub Queries:**

You could add an unbound calculated field (PXDBScalar) in your ARInvoice

To add Sub Queries in BQL, you must do it at the the attribute level. Because you want to query another table, PXDBScalar, would be the best option. If you wanted to query other fields of the same record, PXDBCalced would be more adequate. For more informations about Advanced SQL Attributes please refer to the T200 under Using Advanced SQL Attributes and Acumatica’s help under Help -> Acumatica Framework -> API Reference -> Attributes -> Adhoc SQL for Fields.

Extend the ARInvoice **(V5.1 and below)**

```
public class ARInvoiceExtension : PXCacheExtension<ARInvoice>
{
    public abstract class lastPaymentOrderNbr : IBqlField
    {
    }

    #region LastPaymentOrderNbr
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Payment Order Nbr.")]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<ARAdjust.adjdOrderNbr,
                                 Where<ARAdjust.adjdDocType, Equal<ARInvoice.docType>,
                                    And<ARAdjust.adjdRefNbr, Equal<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>,
                                    OrderBy<Desc<ARAdjust.adjgDocDate>>>))]
    public string LastPaymentOrderNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

A new field has been added to ARInvoice in **V5.2** to get the last payment date so you don't have to add another one:

```
public abstract class lastPaymentDate : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected DateTime? _LastPaymentDate;

/// <summary>
/// The date of the most recent payment associated with this document.
/// </summary>
[PXDate()]
[PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<ARAdjust.adjgDocDate,
 Where<ARAdjust.adjdDocType, Equal<ARInvoice.docType>,
    And<ARAdjust.adjdRefNbr , Equal<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>,
    OrderBy<Desc<ARAdjust.adjgDocDate>>>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Payment Date")]
public virtual DateTime? LastPaymentDate
{
    get
    {
        return this._LastPaymentDate;
    }
    set
    {
        this._LastPaymentDate = value;
    }
}
```

Your PXSelect would then look like this:

*V5.1 and below*

```
public PXSelect<ARInvoice, Where<ARInvoiceExtension.lastPaymentOrderNbr, IsNotNull>> InvoicesTest;
```

*V5.2*

```
public PXSelect<ARInvoice, Where<ARInvoice.lastPaymentDate, IsNotNull>> InvoicesTest;
```

**Inner join on table**

Instead of sub-querying it you could simply add an inner join and filter record that do not have an ARAdjust. You then group by your key fields to avoid duplicates.

```
        public PXSelectJoinGroupBy<ARInvoice, 
                InnerJoin<ARAdjust, On<ARAdjust.adjdRefNbr, Equal<ARInvoice.refNbr>, 
                    And<ARAdjust.adjdDocType, Equal<ARInvoice.docType>>>>, 
                Where<ARAdjust.adjdOrderNbr, IsNotNull>, 
                Aggregate<GroupBy<ARInvoice.docType, 
                    GroupBy<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>> InvoicesTest;
```

Comment: Excellant thankyou - I ended up just checking if the ARInvoice Balance is less than the LineTotal.  But using the last payment date will be much simpler